# how to use the href attribute in django templates

Tags: python, django, url, href

When I try to use a link in my Django template from `/appname/index/` to get to `/appname/detail/###` I am instead getting to `/appname/index/detail/###` which is not what I'm trying to get so my app can't find it in the urlconf of course.

First the urls.py line for the detail page

```
url(r'detail/(?P<jobID>\d+)/$', 'appname.views.detail')
```

Additionally, the root urlconf

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^appname/', include('appname.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Next the template code trying to get there

```
{% for job in jobList %}
    <a href="detail/{{ job.id }}/">{{ job.name }}</a>
```

I'm not sure what else might be applicable information, just ask if you would like to see something else.  I also tried :

```
<a href="{% url 'appname.views.detail' %}/{{ job.id }}">{{ job.name }}</a>
```

But that didn't work either.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: how is the root ulrconf defined? prepend the URL prefix to `/detail...`

Comment: then you need `/appname/detail/{{job_id}}/` Check @Aamir's second answer. That should have worked

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add `/` at start in `href`:

```
<a href="/appname/detail/{{ job.id }}/">{{ job.name }}</a>
```

And for the `url` tag to work you need to do it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'appname.views.detail' jobID=job.id %}">{{ job.name }}</a>
```

Comment: both of those methods are giving me the same destination URL as before

Comment: How you are including `appname` urls in main urlconf file?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, as long as you have defined the url of the page the `href` tag should lead to in `urls.py`, include the absolute path in the format below.

```
Site name: yyyy.com
Url of page to redirect to in urls.py: yyyy.com/signup/

Sample link: <a href="/signup/">Signup</a>
```

You will notice that what goes inside the href tag is sort of appended to the current url. For more dynamic links, you can use some python as of DTL guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose u are at

```
myapp/detail
```

and u want to go at page

```
 myapp/anything
```

U shoud do this

```
<a href="../anything">Page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For django templates
Url.py File

```
app_name = 'app_name'
path('url/', TestView.as_view(), name='the_url'),
path('url//<int:id>', TestView.as_view(), name='the_url'),
```

templates(html.py)

```
 <a href="{% url 'app_name:the_url'  %}">Test</a>
 <a href="{% url 'app_name:the_url' id %}">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, new address is being added after the "/" URL which is not recognised.

Can be solved by adding "/" at the address you are giving at the href attribute.

ex: href:services is wrong
href:/services is to be used to go to services page.